# lazy loading modules angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I've got an app-routing.module.ts like

```typescript
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login', 
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
     path: '', 
     canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
     component: HomeComponent, 
     children: [ 
       //todo w AuthGuard trzeba sprawdzic, czy dane logowania poprawne
      {
         path: 'nationalOneWayTicket', 
         loadChildren: () => import('./national-one-way-ticket/national-one-way-ticket.module').then(m => m.NationalOneWayTicketModule)}
    ]},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: false, useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Also in my app.component.ts I've got this routes :

```typescript
ngOnInit() {
    this.initRoutes();
    this.router.navigate([this.urls.login]);
  }

  private initRoutes(): void {
    const routerConfig = [
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
      {path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: HomeComponent, children: [
        {path: 'nationalOneWayTicket', loadChildren: () => import('./national-one-way-ticket/national-one-way-ticket.module').then(m => m.NationalOneWayTicketModule)}
  ]},
      {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}// todo tutaj dodawać kolejne ścieżki
    ];
    this.router.resetConfig(routerConfig);
```

My HomeComponent is pretty simple it's just html:

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

After loging action I've got

```
 this.router.navigate([this.url.nationalOneWayTicket]);
```

I can see the header but cannot see the html of nationalOneWayTicketModule. Not sure what am I doing wrong

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: no, nothing. Also in Network I can see http://localhost:4200/national-one-way-ticket-national-one-way-ticket-module.js so it seems that the module is loaded, just the ts and html not?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind It works now. I just needed to create a NAtional..RoutingModule which defines specific routing for this part of app, now I can see html of this component :)